# What is before the thunderstorm

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*Sunny morning

After brilliant night,

Wheat fields

Tinted in red,

Road in between

Whispering - love...*

Beautiful, isn't it? Looks tidy and full? Don't trust your first impression... Find out what is before the thunderstorm?

**Hint 1:**

> Each row represents a single word.

**Hint 2:**

> Looking above where thunderstorms exist may help.

**Hint 3:**

> For some first strophe is in place, for others it is not.

Comment: Is it time for hints?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a bit of a stretch, but my first thought was:

> [image]

Sunny morning

> Sunny -> Yellow, morning -> 'M'

After brilliant night

> The signs are brightly illuminated at night.

Wheat fields

> The arches don't look unlike the drooping heads of wheat stalks

Tinted in red

> The red background

Road in between

> Referencing the middle 'road' in the M, between the two outer 'roads'

Whispering - love

> I'm lovin it

What is before the thunderstorm?

> This is clearly the wrong answer, but I'm enjoying making it fit. 
>  According to this McDonald's ad, Ronald McDonald is what/who appears before the thunderstorm (it's just cloudy beforehand):  [McDonald's Thunderstorm Ad](http://www.ispot.tv/ad/7ogD/mcdonalds-happy-meal-cloudy-day)

Comment: That is amazing, but I'm totally lost on how it comes before the thunderstorm.

Comment: I can add - and what is thunderstorm itself?

Comment: Updated to reflect a (ridiculous) but strangely fitting answer to the thunderstorm part. Thanks google.

Comment: oh! @kamenf's comment is making me think the thunderstorm is actually a growling stomach (from hunger)?

Comment: @dperry In fact, the things are far far more sublime... and in the same time ordinary :)